# What is the purpose of the "Remote Domain" ticker on NetBeans IDE when adding a glassfish server instance?

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

The Next or finish button is disabled until a proper glassfish installation path to the "local machine" is supplied to the "Installation Location" input box, even though "Remote Domain" is ticked.
How is ORACLE defining: "Remote Domain"?

Answer (score 0):

A remote domain is remote (on another computer) and not local (on your computer). I guess that is what you already expected.

That you have to select a valid installation path even if you want to setup a remote domain seems to be a NetBeans bug.